# Real-time "like" retrieving with instagram api

Tags: instagram

Is there any way in Instagram API to immediately retrieve new "like" setted to user's any media? User is authorized

Answer (score 0):

There is no real-time notification available for "Likes". Please see their documentation for what is available: https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/